# Use different Azure AD B2C user flows for sign in/sign up in Hosted Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, blazor

I have set up the sign-in-and-sign-up user flow for my hosted blazor wasm app according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-7.0. Now I want to have different user flows for sign in(`B2C_1_SIGN_IN`) and sign up(`B2C_1_SIGN_UP`) for sign-in and sign up links on the web page. This is because I want to create user in local db only after sign-up.

The original `appsettings.json` for client

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://***.b2clogin.com/***.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SIGN_UP_SIGN_IN",
    "ClientId": "****,
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  }
```

The original `appsettings.json` for server

```
{

  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://***.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "Domain": "**.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Scopes": "API.ReadWrite",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SIGN_UP_SIGN_IN",
},...
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Use different Azure AD B2C user flows for sign in/sign up in Hosted Blazor WebAssembly

In `Azure AD B2C` => `User flows` => `New User flow`,
We have different options to create `Sign In` and `Sign Up` user flows separately.

[image]

***Sign In User flow:***

[image]

***Sign Up User flow:***

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#sign-in-flow-overview)

> Users cannot sign up for an Azure AD B2C Local Account.

We can create a [Custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) for both Sign in and Sign Up.

The Authority in Client Configuration has to be updated with the custom Policy URL.

Instead of `SignUpSignInPolicyId`, we need to have different `PolicyId` -  `SignInPolicyId` and `SignUpPolicyId`.

Below are the configurations in my `appsettings.json`.

***`appsettings.json` for Server App:***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://****.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "****.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "**********",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignIn",
    "SignUpPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUp",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/SignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile",
    "EnablePiiLogging": true,
    "ClientSecret": "Client secret from app-registration. Check user secrets/azure portal.",
    "ClientCertificates": []
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
 }
```

If you are configuring only for `Sign In` , then remove the `SignUpPolicyId` from`appsettings.json` file.

***`appsettings.json` for Client App:***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "Authority": "https://****.b2clogin.com/blazorserver.onmicrosoft.com/CustomPolicy****",
    "ValidateAuthority": false
  },
  "ServerApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://****.onmicrosoft.com/******",
    "Scopes": "https://blazorserver.onmicrosoft.com/****/access_as_user"
  }
}
```

Thanks @Taiseer Joudeh for the explanation.

Refer this [Blog](https://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/)  and [custom policies](https://www.cloudpartner.fi/?p=5856) for more details.